# Django validation error u"'' value must be a decimal number."

Tags: python, django, decimal

I am trying to get data from a form, the form is reproduced a number of times based on a list. One form for each item. The form consists of a checkbox and a textfield. If the checkbox is checked then I need the accompanying textfield data as well.

view:

```
        for item in request.POST.getlist('item_list'):
            item_id = int(item)
            item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
            item_name = item.name
            print item_name


            list = List(name = item_name, created_on = now, edited_on = now)

            for price in request.POST.getlist('price'):
                print price
                list_item.price = price
                list_item.save()
            #item.delete()
```

Its not shown above but `now = timezone.now()`.

template:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for item in item_list %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}} <input type="text" name="price"><br>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Add Items">

</form>
```

This returns a validationerror `[u"'' value must be a decimal number."]`. I can't figure out why it would be saying the numbers I'm inputting are not decimals. Thanks for your help.

Update:

The output when I put `print request.POST.getlist('price')` is `[u'2.55', u'4.32', u'23.421', u'3.00', u'', u'']`

Comment: Try replacing `list_item.price = price` with `list_item.price = Decimal(price)`.

Comment: I've tried that but then I get a `global name 'Decimal' is not defined`

Comment: Don't forget an import statement: `from decimal import Decimal`

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting `Invalid literal for Decimal: u''` and I've confirmed the correct value is in the post data.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You have a problem that the `price` is empty. What is the output of `request.POST.getlist('price')`?

Comment: Please see the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are empty `price`s in the list, skip them. Also, cast strings to decimals:

```
from decimal import Decimal

...

for price in request.POST.getlist('price'):
    if not price:
        continue
    list_item.price = Decimal(price)
    list_item.save()
```

Comment: That fixed all of my errors however now whichever value is entered last is the value that is saved for all items. In the terminal my print command returns all correct values that I entered.

Comment: And `print list_item.price` returns the correct value in the terminal as well.

Comment: Not exactly, if I enter to distinct values for two distinct items they end up with the same value.