# Django form replicates data

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to get data from a form, the form is reproduced a number of times based on a list. One form for each item. The form consists of a checkbox and a textfield. If the checkbox is checked then I need the accompanying textfield data as well.

I asked a related question here:

[Django validation error u"'' value must be a decimal number."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496941/django-validation-error-u-value-must-be-a-decimal-number)

Which was mostly solved however now I have a new issue.

view:

```
        for item in request.POST.getlist('item_list'):
            item_id = int(item)
            item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
            item_name = item.name
            print item_name


            list = List(name = item_name, created_on = now, edited_on = now)

            for price in request.POST.getlist('price'):
                                if not price:
                                    continue
                print price
                list_item.price = Decimal(price)
                list_item.save()
            item.delete()
```

Its not shown above but `now = timezone.now()`.

template:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for item in item_list %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}} <input type="text" name="price"><br>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Add Items">

</form>
```

When I submit the form it now runs through both loops twice and the final prices for all items are identical. I determined this by inserting print functions throughout my code and analyzing what is displayed. I guess I understand where the issue is, the question is how to correct it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a builtin data type.

Comment: That's not the actual name of the variable, I changed several to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your template repeats the following line many times:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}} <input type="text" name="price">
```

That creates a form with the fields `item` and `price` duplicated for every line.  That is not a good way to create a form.

Instead, generate the lines with unique values for the `name=` attributes.  For example,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item_{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}
<input type="text" name="price_{{item.id}}">
```

Then back in your view, use this loop to find the matching pairs:

```
for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
    if not name.startswith('item_'):
        continue
    name, item_id = key.split('_')
    if name == 'item':
        price = request.POST.get('price_%s' % item_id)
        # fetch the item, set the price
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what's happening here in the first line of your views.py code 'for key, value'. Specifically what key and value are.

Comment: That makes sense thanks. One last thing, why is it key.spit as opposed to value.split?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, it returns an error `need more than 1 value to unpack` at line `name, item_id = key.split('_')`

Comment: The `key` is the field `name`, and `value` is the field's value.  The keys will be "item_#" or "price_#".  If you have other fields in your form (that don't have a name with '_'), you'll see that error.  I've added a line to the view to catch this case.